# How to create JDBC upsert query based on 2 keys

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, upsert

I want to preform a upsert(update or create) based on 2 column:
if the column A and Column B exsists in the table then update values else create a new row with this key.

```
//pasdo code for my query
if(table.key1 == firstKey && table.key2 == secKey){
 //update values for the row with key1, key2
} else {
//create a row with firstKey, secKey as keys
}
```

I have a oracle sql server on the backend.

Comment: So the question is...

Comment: How to create such query....

Comment: Just google for update and insert query you will get lot of example.

Comment: I did it, still didnt found the missing part - based it on 2 columns.

Comment: in where clause add two conditions

Comment: Trying. will post the results.

Comment: You may be looking for [MERGE](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/merge-statement).

Comment: Yes that is the opertion I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something similar like this...
In oracle, dual is like dummy table. it does not have any rows.. it helps to create temporary table needed for merge query
following may not exact SQL syntax..

```
merge into table m using (select firstKey,secKey from dual d) on 
(m.key1 = d.firstKey and m.key2 = d.secKey )
         when not matched then insert... -- put insert statement here
             when matched then update .. -- put statemenet here
```